# How to connect DB using psql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, psql

Hi I wanted to connect to Postgres that I created on Google Cloud SQL using psql. In the [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql) it says to connect to the database do this

```
psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=INSTANCE_IP"
```

I have tried to do so using my Terminal on my Linux laptop, but after I press enter, nothing happen... I'm confused what to do next? How should I create a table, query etc?

[image]

Comment: How did you configure your Cloud SQL instance connectivity? Public IP is enabled? Did you authorize your home network? (or wherever you're running psql from)

Comment: Also, does the connection eventually timeout (I suspect you're waiting on a TCP timeout which means 45-60 seconds).

Comment: Hey @GabeWeiss sorry for my late reply. I have enabled public IP and have added my home network. I just tried it again today and it worked. I guess it just takes a few hours until it works... Because I didn't change anything and now it works.

Comment: No worries! If you created the instance without the authorized network, then after it's created add your authorized network, it DOES take a minute or two to activate. Shouldn't be that long? But either way, glad it's working for you now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to connect to my PostgreSQL successfully by following the documentation you provided.

Instead of using What's My IP, I've used the public IP assigned for my instance:

[image: 1]

After executing this code on my terminal:

```
psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=[public-ip-address]"
```

I've successfully connected to my PostgreSQL instance. See screenshot below:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also use that Public IP Address, but I don't know why it didn't work last time. Now it works already, maybe it just takes a few hours to be active (?) Thanks for anwering.